# How to trace specific methods/classes with NewRelic in Java?

Tags: java, newrelic, javaagents

I know there is a way to trace any methods you want, thanks to an annotation named `@Trace`, but if i use this annotation I will need to alter source code for all methods that I want to trace, not a good way I think. So, do you know if any of below is possible or not?

1- Tracing a custom annotation by xml configuration. (For example, tracing all methods which are annotated with `@CustomAnnotation`)

2- Tracing all methods of all implementers/extenders of a Interface/Class, again by xml configuration.

3- Do you know any other generic ways to success this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why XML? Ever since the introduction of annotations in Java 5, most frameworks and libraries have been actively trying to reduce the amount of XML-based configuration in favor of Java-based configuration, which is often more flexible

Comment: I want to separate my concerns, therefore i do not want to add NewRelic code/config to my source code.

Answer (score 0):

New Relic does allow [instrumentation using XML files](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/custom-instrumentation/java-instrumentation-xml). Some [examples](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/custom-instrumentation/java-xml-instrumentation-examples).

There is also the [custom instrumentation editor](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/custom-instrumentation/custom-instrumentation-editor-instrument-ui).